# Ansible Module : module_stderr and module_stdout are both empty

Tags: python, ansible

I'm calling a custom module `delete_sdb_domain.py` in the playbook to delete the Simple DB domain in AWS after delete Simian Army Chaos Monkey. The task can be executed successfully, but there are error message for the Ansible Module.

Here is the playbook:

```
     # call ansible module in the playbook 

  - name: Delete Simian Army SimpleDB domain
         delete_sdb_domain:
         sdb_domain_name: "SIMIAN_ARMY_{{ stack_prefix }}"

         when:
              "stack_query.rc == 0"
         tags:
              - delete
```

here is the module `delete_sdb_domain.py`:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

    # Delete SimpleDB Domain

    from ansible.module_utils.basic import *
    import boto3

    def delete_sdb_domain(sdb_domain_name):
        sdb = boto3.client('sdb')
        sdb.delete_domain(DomainName=sdb_domain_name)

    def main():
        module = AnsibleModule(
        argument_spec = dict(
         sdb_domain_name = dict(required=True, type='str')
                        )
        )

        delete_sdb_domain(module.params['sdb_domain_name'])



       if __name__ == '__main__':
           main()
```

and here is the error:

```
TASK [Delete Simian Army SimpleDB domain] 
*************************************************************************
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {
   "changed": false, 
   "module_stderr": "", 
   "module_stdout": "", 
    "rc": 0
}

MSG:

    MODULE FAILURE
```

Comment: how do I know what's the exact error causing this ?

Comment: Please fix the indentation; both: in YAML and Python code.

Comment: thank you for the reminder, yes, there should be indentation there, I just forgot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible reports an error, because you don't provide the required JSON object with the result.

Have a look at [the tutorial on new module development](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html#new-module-development):

> ```
> # seed the result dict in the object
> # we primarily care about changed and state
> # change is if this module effectively modified the target
> # state will include any data that you want your module to pass back
> # for consumption, for example, in a subsequent task
> result = dict(
>     changed=False,
>     original_message='',
>     message=''
> )
>
> # ...
>
> # in the event of a successful module execution, you will want to
> # simple AnsibleModule.exit_json(), passing the key/value results
> module.exit_json(**result)
> ```

Comment: and yes, you are right, I should put this JSON object at the end of Ansible Module which I forgot, still a newbie! ; )